# Understanding %20 and blob with grammar

Tags: javascript, blob

I am not that good or familiar with JS.

I was reading on web about exporting data in table into excel [from following article](https://www.codexworld.com/export-html-table-data-to-excel-using-javascript/)

There they have used this function example

```
function exportTableToExcel(tableID, filename = ''){
    var downloadLink;
    var dataType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
    var tableSelect = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var tableHTML = tableSelect.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');

    // Specify file name
    filename = filename?filename+'.xls':'excel_data.xls';

    // Create download link element
    downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

    if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
        var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', tableHTML], {
            type: dataType
        });
        navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob( blob, filename);
    }else{
        // Create a link to the file
        downloadLink.href = 'data:' + dataType + ', ' + tableHTML;

        // Setting the file name
        downloadLink.download = filename;

        //triggering the function
        downloadLink.click();
    }
}
```

Here, I am unable to comprehend the following lines

1. `var tableHTML = tableSelect.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');`
2. `var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', tableHTML], {type: dataType });
           navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob( blob, filename);`

Can someone help me in understanding it.

Comment: The first line uses https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first element performs a basic URL encoding replacing spaces with their URL equivalent `%20`.

The second thing creates the `Blob` instance that starts with the unicode character corresponding to the hex `feff`, and then follows with the contents of the `tableHTML` variable.

Finally, the `navigator` call causes the browser to prompt the user to download the file.

**Edit:**

> Can you please share this in details (/ /g, '%20')

It's a JavaScript regex as @Felix Kling pointed out. An inline regex in JavaScript starts with a forward slash and ends with a forward slash. The `g` means it's applied globally, rather than the first match.

Comment: Can you please share this in details `(/ /g, '%20')`

Comment: @anny123: Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace